# Java Hikari How to solve SSL factory error when using org.postgresql.ssl.jdbc4.LibPQFactory

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, ssl, hikaricp

I'm trying to create a DB connection using Hikari data source
this is my Parameters, i need to use a sslfactory
when i use LibPQFactor it fails with the error below, how can i solve it ?
i want to clarify that i must **NOT** use `org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory`
so Please dont offer it

Thoese are the SSL params I use to concatenate to my JDBC URL:

```
"?sslmode=verify-ca&ssl=true&sslrootcert=/opt/datorama/cert/global-bundle.pem&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.jdbc4.LibPQFactor";
```

This is the stack trace

```
Error creating bean with name 'hikariConfigDataSource' defined in com.datorama.datasource.OLTPHikariDatasourceConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool: The SSLSocketFactory class provided org.postgresql.ssl.jdbc4.LibPQFactor could not be instantiated.
```

full stack trace

```
s org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceBase' defined in com.company.datasource.OLTPHikariDatasourceConfig: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'buildHikariDataSource' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hikariConfigDataSource' defined in com.company.datasource.OLTPHikariDatasourceConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool: The SSLSocketFactory class provided org.postgresql.ssl.jdbc4.LibPQFactor could not be instantiated.
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:342)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:706)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1361)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1208)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1307)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1227)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcesso…","_serviceName":"dtr-company-web"}*
```

- 

Comment: I wonder why you have your own config class and not use the defaults. Please include the **full stacktrace** not only the snippet you have now.

Comment: Check your spelling.  Factory, not Factor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Jjanes
i had a typo and missing a y in the factory name

```
?sslmode=verify-ca&ssl=true&sslrootcert=/var/lib/jetty/global-bundle.pem&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.jdbc4.LibPQFactory
```